# How to know collection view scrolling of items reach to end (at the last item) when grouping implemented in Xamarin Forms iOS?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to display a button when scroll reach to end. I tried multiple ways.

1) Using "RemainingItemsThresholdReached" but is is having known issue for iOS. [Here it is](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10643)

2) Using "Scrolled" event. But here problem is "LastVisibleItemIndex" starts with 0 when new group visible on view. So comparing with overall item count is not possible. Also I can not identify  which group is visible on screen.

3) Add button in "GroupFooterTemplate". But here problem is my button is visible at end of all group which I don't want. I want to display at end of last group only.

4) Add button in "FooterTemplate". It is not displaying in ios. Here is code of that.

```
<CollectionView.FooterTemplate>
     <DataTemplate><Frame BackgroundColor="GreenYellow"
                                       Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="40">
                                <Label Style="{StaticResource Header}"
                                       Text="LOAD MORE" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                </Frame></DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.FooterTemplate>
```

Please let me know if any solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Add button in "FooterTemplate". It is not displaying in ios. Here is code of that.

If you want to add a button on the end of CollectionView(not each group) . You need to use `<CollectionView.FooterTemplate>` instead of `<CollectionView.FooterTemplate>`

```
<CollectionView.Footer>             
     <Button Text="xxx" />
</CollectionView.Footer>
```

Comment: Sorry if I not make it clear, but I want that for Collection View not for List View.